# Split a File into Multiple Objects Functionally

Tags: .net, functional-programming, f#

I want to read a file into a collection of objects. The data (it's a Leica PTX file if you're curious) is formatted as follows:

```
640 [begin item #1: number of columns]
480 [number of rows]
0 0 0 [position information: 3x3 matrix]
0 0 0 [position ctd]
0 0 0 [position ctd]
1 0 0 0 [calibration information: 3x4 matrix]
0 1 0 0 [calibration ctd]
0 0 1 0 [calibration ctd]
1.1 2.2 3.3 0.5 [point 1: X Y Z I]
-0.2 2.3 1.4 0.2 [point 2: X Y Z I]
...
3.9 1.2 -7.7 0.8 [point n: X Y Z I]
640 [begin item #2: number of columns]
480 [number of rows]
0 0 0 [position information]
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 0 0 0 [calibration information]
0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0
0.2 1.3 -2.1 0.4 [point 1 of item #2]
... [etc]
```

I.e. Two lines each containing a single float/double (as text) signal the beginning of a new item, and no other lines are exactly one number.

It's easy to do if there's only one item per file, it's a simple `fold` operation. It would also be relatively straightforward to do with a `while` type loop that keeps state, but I'm new to functional programming and wondering if there isn't a more concise and elegant way to do this functionally with standard tools (like `reduce`, `fold`, `split`/`partition`, etc). The best solutions I've come up with so far involve "peeking" ahead using lists or arrays, but I'd like something that allows for the possibility of a sequence that is consumed as it iterates for maximum generality. (I'm using F# and .NET but I don't see this as a language-specific problem.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Can you share some example data?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question. Does it make it more clear what I'm struggled with?

Comment: Looks like a job for a parser combinator library. I'm not an F# guru but Googling "F# parser combinators" turns up [this](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I think learning about parser combinators is an overkill for parsing something that's this simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the whole file is small enough to fit into memory, then I think one way would be to parse the file into a list and then process the list piece by piece, something like:

```fs
let parseItem (columnsString::rowsString::rest) =
    let columns = int columnsString
    let rows = int rowsString
    let position, rest = parsePosition rest
    let calibration, rest = parseCalibration rest
    let points, rest = parsePoints columns rows rest
    (columns, rows, position, calibration, points), rest

let rec parseItems = function
    | [] -> []
    | lines ->
        let item, restLines = parseItem lines
        let restItems = parseItems restLines
        item :: restItems
```

As you surely noticed, this code is pretty repetitive, but you can simplify it using the state workflow (known as state monad in Haskell) from [ExtCore](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore):

```fs
let parseItem =
    state {
        let! columns = parseInt
        let! rows = parseInt
        let! position = parsePosition
        let! calibration = parseCalibration
        let! points = parsePoints columns rows
        return columns, rows, position, calibration, points
    }

let rec parseItems = function
    | [] -> [], []
    | lines ->
        state {
            let! item = parseItem
            let! restItems = parseItems
            return item::restItems
        } <| lines
```

Comment: Thanks - passing `rest` *back* from the inner function calls is exactly the sort of thing I was trying to think of, and couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

I'd wager that the most popular tool in the Haskell world for this sort of problem is [**parser combinators**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator).  The classic library for this is [parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec), but for a machine generated file format the [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) library is generally a better choice (faster parsing at the cost of less friendly error reporting—a good tradeoff when you're reading large files that were not written by humans).

There is [an excellent tutorial demonstrating attoparsec's use by parsing log files](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/attoparsec).

Attoparsec is popular enough that [somebody tried to port it to F#](https://github.com/pocketberserker/FsAttoparsec), but I've never even written an F# program, so I definitely don't have any way of judging the quality of that library.  There's also a [port of the regular (non-"atto") Haskell parsec library to F#](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/), that might be worth looking at—it also comes with a [tutorial](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html).

If you wish to understand a little bit of how parser combinators work under the hood, Graham Hutton and Erik Meijer wrote two simple tutorials showing simplified internals.  The first, I believe, is an abridged version of the second:

- http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pearl.pdf
- http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/monparsing.pdf

These are in Haskell but if you know F# you will likely be able to follow a lot of it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly one of functional programming's best use cases, but most languages have a construct that will create an infinite stream of lines, which you generally feed into a `fold` with an initial state.  Here's an example in Scala (sorry, I don't know F#):

```
val lines = io.Source.stdin.getLines
val state = lines.foldLeft(initialState)(processLine)
```

Basically, the `processLine` function is whatever you would put in your `while` loop, and it returns a new state each time through.  Inside it, you can use `split`, regexes, pattern matching, or even parser combinators if you're brave.

I can't claim the functional solution ends up *more* elegant with something this stateful, but it does have the advantage that the wrong path is usually obvious pretty quickly.